# 1098T left off 2017 return

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, mistakes

I forgot to include a form 1098T to my daughters 2017 tax return, she did recieve a refund for income she had during that year, the 1098T was from her fall semester at Texas A&M where she is currently enrolled and using loans for all her college expenses, can I or do I need to file an amended return for that year?

Answer (score 1):

**Can I or do I need to file an amended return for that year?**

She doesn't need to, but it could be worthwhile to do so. If she qualifies for any education credits and her return doesn't already reflect the amount of qualified education expenses paid, then she could have additional refund coming her way. If the inclusion of the 1098-T has no impact, then there's no point in filing an amended return.

When you are owed a refund, you have 3-years to file/amend a return to claim it.

Edit: Since you claim her as a dependent, you should see if there is impact on your tax return. Also, the American Opportunity Tax Credit is partially refundable, so if she qualified for that credit it could have benefit for her.

Comment: thank you, it should not affect her refund, I still claim her as a dependent, she made minimal moneys that year, small refund recieved. thanks for your comment

Comment: If you claim her then it may be worth it to amend your return if it creates a larger education credit for you for that year.